# How to have the latest atualizations of the Database displayed in an ASP.NET MVC 3 page?

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

Maybe the question title is misleading (I hope not), but that's my problem:

I have a form that sends new reports to the page, which then displays all the reports in a list (both the form and the list are in the same page). When I send a new report, and then refresh (insistently pressing the F5 button, which is now almost broken), this new report (which is a row in the database) doesn't get displayed. I'm well sure that the database is updated. If I insert a new row column manually, the same problem still occur. 
When I stop and start again de development server (or refresh the IIS), this report then gets displayed (which is a bit annoying).

My scenario is basically ASP.NET MVC 3, using EF 4, linking to a MySQL database through their own .net Connector.

Any ideas?

Comment: Care to show some code or we should be guessing?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov solved the problem. My mistake was to use a static object to hold the entity object.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and accept it so that the question is closed out. Your answer could also help someone else in the future.

Comment: @Bruno , I second benjamin. Post your comment as answer and accept it

Comment: @Bruno: You can anser your question by yourself. And i think that in 2 days you can accept your answer and close yor question.

Comment: You're all right, sorry for my mistake.